# (Django) Why would my code not execute in an .html template?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

this is my first post. I'll try get things right first time. I am having a play around with django and slowly creating a dummy store website. I'm following along a Corey Schafer YouTube tutorial and I didn't have this issue on my first run, so scratching my head now!

My problem is that my .html template is not displaying the listing item when I run the page. I still see the `<h1>DaftPrices Store Homepage</h1>`, but not the listings.

This is my template (store_home.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>DaftPrices - Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>DaftPrices Store Homepage</h1>
    {% for listing in listings %}
        <p>{{ listing.item }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

This is saved in a store dir, inside a templates dir, inside the store app.
[Image of directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzGhT.png)

This is my app views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


listings = [
    {
        'seller': 'ABCDEFG',
        'title': 'Something to sell',
        'date_posted': '28th August 3030'
    }
]


def store_home(request):
    context = {'listing': listings}
    return render(request, 'store/store_home.html', context)


def store_about(request):
    return render(request, 'store/store_about.html')
```

To clarify, the page pulls the template, but the "code" isn't working

I have tried re-writing the dummy listings and changing the variables. I wasn't expecting this to do anything (and it didn't), but that was my first shot.

I checked my project's settings.py folder to double check that I had added the store app into "installed apps". I believe this is correct, and was identical to what I did on my previous run without the issue:

store app ; apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class StoreConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'store'
```

project ; settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'store.apps.StoreConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

I've had a look at other stackoverflow listings which seem like they are relevant to my problem, but I'm struggling to identify the key info other than making sure the `context` is called for correctly. I can't see any issues with mine, hence I'm here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the `s` in `listings` context key:

```py
def store_home(request):
    context = {'listing': listings}
    return render(request, 'store/store_home.html', context)
```

```py
def store_home(request):
    context = {'listings': listings}
    return render(request, 'store/store_home.html', context)
```

Corey did awesome job. I have completed his course and I work with Django today.

Comment: Hi Nixon, thanks for the speedy response. His video's are my go-to usually as they're great.

Bit confused with what you're recommending as the code snippet you have given is what I've got currently and the 's' is present in the variable name (with the dummy data) and in the context key? I must be missing something glaringly obvious!

Comment: @Purple_Floyd I have edited my answer to be clearer - in template you have to refer the context with exactly the same string (key is important here, not the value or the variable).

Comment: Thanks so much for elaborating. I get it now :)